# Dynamic page embedding in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, html, dynamic, embedding

I have a tag like this in my HTML page:

```
<embed src="http://..." style='...'>
```

Using Python-Flask I hand over a varying source address and store it in `window.dynamicEmbedding`. Now I want to change the src value dynamically on page load in a compact way. I imagine something this

```
<embed src=<script>document.write(window.dynamicEmbedding)</script> style='...'>
```

which is surely not possible. Is there anyway to realize this without a lot of coding?

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the logic you want for deciding which urls to serve. If you simply want a random url, that would be fairly easy in javascript. Simply place the urls in an array and use math.Random to select an index. Each time the page loads, a new random index can be generated, and a new url is selected to be passed to your embed.

Since you're using flask though, the easier way - particularly if you need more complex selection criteria than random - would be to write the selection logic into the python, and pass only the selected url to the template. You have a flask view like this:

```
import random

@app.route('/')
def video_page():
    urls = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','etc']
    url_selection = random.choice(urls)
    return render_template('video_page.html', url=url_selection)
```

Comment: Hmmm ... unfortunately I cannot use flask directly, since I work with JQuery tabs. So the index.html imports the tabs and one tab embeds an external web page. So I can hand over the source of the embedded page from flask to index.html (as you described) but not in the flask way to the tab, i.e. need some javascript.

Comment: Solved this now by adding <div id='myDynamicEmbedding' style='width:100%;height:100%;'> </div> and calling var myEmbedding = `
  <embed src="${window.dynamicEmbedding}"  ...`; $('#myDynamicEmbedding').html(myEmbedding); which works but seems not to be very "elegant".

Comment: JS can pass a value directly to the src attribute of an embed tag. Leave the embed in the HTML with src="", and then have a script tag with

$(#myDynamicEmbedding).setAttribute("src", window.dynamicEmbedding);